# Some Tamil script is not supporting in IOS 10.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, local-storage, tamil

In my application I am using different languages like Tamil and Kannada. In app I need to save data in above mentioned languages. But my problem is some Tamil Script is not getting read on **IOS 10.3** devices. But it's working perfectly on devices that runs on OS below 10.3 and on simulators.

I have tried NSUTF8StringEncoding and whitespace removal. Still I get the same error.

```
 NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:[dataPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *dataPathDestination=[data stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                       [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

Is there any specific frameworks for supporting local languages ?

Only a part of my script is throwing error, remaining works fine.

Example Tamil Script

> "அரங்கநாத சுவாமி கோயில் (ஸ்ரீரங்கம்)"

Comment: have you tried changing ur fonts?

Comment: Yes, I tried with all possiblities then also same error.

Answer (score 0):

Tamil needs UTF16 at least. Keep that in mind when reading or writing the data.